# Unable to link elementary HDF5 1.10.6 program

Tags: c, hdf5

1. Built the HDF5 ver 1.10.6 on Win 10 64 bit using VS 2019 CMake utility, set the CONFIGURATION_TYPE as Debug
2. This build, during test phase, shows 3 abort warnings, but on retry, those tests flow through, thus has 100% success.
3. The installation was uneventful. Installs hdf5.dll, and hdf5_D.dll as well.
4. When I run the most elementary C program reproduced below :

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "hdf5.h"
    #include <stdio.h>


    int main() {

        printf("Hello World !");
        hid_t       file_id;        //File Identifier used by HDF5 system
        herr_t      status;

        file_id = H5FCreate("test_file.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
        status = H5FClose(file_id);
        exit(0);
    }
```

I get compile time warnings and errors :

```
1.Warning   C4013   'H5FCreate' undefined; assuming extern returning int
2.Warning   C4013   'H5FClose' undefined; assuming extern returning int
3.Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol H5FCreate referenced in function main
4.Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol H5FClose referenced in function main
5.Error LNK1120 2 unresolved externals Test_HDF5_C
```

5. The include path has been specified in the Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories
6. The library path has been similarly specified in Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories
7. The library path has also been specified in Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories
8. The libraries specified Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies are : szip.lib;zlib.lib;hdf5.lib - this version fails as above
   9.szip.lib;zlib.lib;hdf5_D.lib - same failure
9. Among many experiments, have tried to build only static libraries (which is what I eventually would need) and faced the same errors.
10. Finally, the compiler warning is most amusing as the screen popup displays *int H5FCreate()* when the mouse hovers over the text, but the warning says H5FCreate undefined during compile time.

Would be happy to share the long list of experiments that have already been done...
Is indeed my first adventure with HDF5 so any advice will be helpful. Thanks..

Comment: the first two warnings say that the header file is missing or not correct.  The 3 linker problems say the library is not found

Comment: did you go through the `configure` step?  Did you go through the `build` step? Did you go through the `test` step?  Did you go through the `install` step?   were they ALL completely successful?

Comment: Did you change to the `release_docs/` sub directory then work through all the details in the `INSTALL` file?

Comment: @user3629249 This is Win 10 64 bit env where the config step is part of the cmake file. Indeed the build was completed, the install was handled by a NSIS Sw that generated an exe file, which was run to install it in the directory C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.10.6\ .. the lib directory has many libs, the include directory has the .H files .. the library hdf5_D.lib is present, so is hdf5.lib. Finally, your question on INSTALL (INSTALL_Windows) file, yes, the procedures outlined in Step 2 (after preconditions) have been followed...